# How to connect the stderr in netcat?

Tags: command-line, networking, bash, 20.04, netcat

Suppose i have two shells (A and B). And i execute command below for first shell:

```
nc -lvp 7777 -e /usr/bin/bash
```

And in the second shell i execute :

```
nc localhost 7777
```

After that, i type 'something' in the first second shell but the *stderr* is in the first shell below:

```
bash: line 1: something: command not found
```

I want to put *stderr* in the second shell not the first shell.
What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is applicable. I just did some tests but couldn't make it work because of quotes. Maybe someone can make this work?

Listener:

```
nc -lvp 7777 -e '/usr/bin/bash -c "bash 2>&1"'
```

But you can do it manually. From the already open shell you start another shell with stderr redirection.
So after you establish a connection and have a shell you run the following.

```
bash 2>&1
```

It opens another shell but this time stderr redirected to stdout.

Answer (score -1):

This works on windows. Based on this example you should find a way to make it work on linux. It runs two cmd.exe but it gets the job done.

```
ncat 127.0.0.1 4444 -e "cmd /c (cmd 2>&1)"
```

Comment: How is this applicable on Ubuntu?